# ssrs 2008 repeat parent group for child group

Tags: reporting-services

[image]

But I want to achieve this:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks.
Nian

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you edit your question and add some more details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "Grp" as parent group and "Sg" as child group right ? So add columns "Grp" and "sg" outside the group and hide the grouping columns. 
[image]

As per above screenshot

1. Add a table in design pane
2. First add attributes for 3 columns OwnerID, Name and City
3. right click on ownerID detail cell and add parent group of ownerID, new group column will be created here as 1st highlighted column. Click on it and add child group as Name(another group column will be created).
4. At last hide both the group columns.

Comment: Yes"Grp" as parent group and "Sg" as child group. I tried add columns out side group. But it seems not working as expected. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thank you, I got your point and it works. And one thing is you can delete the grouping columns (grp, sg) but choose 'keep the group' instead of hide the grouping columns.

Comment: And to be clear, the key is to put grouping columns inside details. Thanks again.